# How to solve this tetration equation analytically?

Tags: exponentiation, problem-solving

$ x^{x^{x^{x}}}=5 $

[Here is what tetration is about](https://brilliant.org/wiki/tetration/)

Note : numerically method **isn't** what I want. (Sorry for I didn't emphasize it before.)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "analytically"? From what set is $x$ allowed to take values from? The Reals?

Comment: The Lambert-W-function might "save the day" , if not you will have to apply numerical methods (the Lambert-W-function , strictly speaking, is also a numerical method). Even $x^x=5$ cannot be solved "directly" (for example like a quadratic equation). And this equation is vastly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^{x^{x^x}}-5$$
we find a zero with Newton's method
$$f'(x)=x^{x^{x^x}} \left(x^{x^x-1}+x^{x^x} \log x \left(x^{x-1}+x^x \log x (\log x+1)\right)\right)$$
We set $x_0=1.5$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$

I got the following results

$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
n & x_n & error \\
\hline
 0 & 1.5 &  \\
 1 & 1.83748 & 0.337477 \\
 2 & 1.79603 & 0.0414445 \\
 3 & 1.74805 & 0.0479864 \\
 4 & 1.70007 & 0.0479734 \\
 5 & 1.66681 & 0.0332666 \\
 6 & 1.65618 & 0.0106251 \\
 7 & 1.65539 & 0.000786085 \\
 8 & 1.6553947522 & 3.85\times 10^{-6} \\
 9 & 1.6553909024 & 9.16\times 10^{-11} \\
\end{array}
$$

Thus the solution with $9$ exact decimals is $x\approx 1.655390902$.

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  But it is a half numerically method, which isn't really what i want. Sorry for I didn't articulate it in the description.

Comment: @giao as peter wrote in the comments, even $x^x=5$ has no "simple" solution, let alone this one!

Comment: Ohh, fine.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If
$$x=\sin \left(\frac{8 \pi }{35}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{44}\right)$$
$$x^{x^{x^x}} =4.9999978$$

Comment: if $x=\frac{80000}{48327}$ then $$x^{x^{x^{x}}}=4.999945$$